# Finding an unknown length of a side using sohcahtoa (Trigonometry)

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, trigonometry

I was trying to make a function to find the length of an unknown side in a right-angled triangle using sohcahtoa (which we were taught in school).

I started it off like this.

```
def trigonometry(angle, side_length, side_respective_to_angle, unknown):
    sohcahtoa = [
        ['opposite', 'hypotenuse', 'adjacent']
        [[], math.sin(angle), math.tan(angle)]
        [math.sin(angle), [], math.cos(angle)]
        [math.tan(angle), math.cos(angle), []]
    ]
```

So now I can match up the side I have and the unknown side to sine, cosine or tangent using:

```
index1 = sohcahtoa[0].index(side_respective_to_angle)
index2 = sohcahtoa.index(unknown)
function = sohcahtoa[index1+1][index2]
```

Then I attempted to figure out how the program would have to rearrange the equation by using the order of sohcahtoa. Eg:

*[if side_respective_to_angle was the hypotenuse and unknown was opposite]*

function(angle) = unknown / side_respective_to_angle

function(angle) * side_respective_to_angle = unknown

This is where I am stuck. Could someone assist me in completing the aforementioned task?

Comment: I can not entirely follow what you are trying to do. You `sohcahtoa` list is not well-formed, so how _exactly_ does that list look? What is `side_respective_to_angle`, then length of a side? Note that `list.index(float)` might not work does to floating point rounding errors. Also, at that level of the (nested?) list, there are no numbers at all. Maybe you should add an example for us to better understand your idea.

Comment: For example: trigonometry(30, 2, 'hypotenuse', 'opposite')

Comment: It is the first item in sohcahtoa[0]

Comment: So wouldn't sohcahtoa[0].index('opposite') = 0 @tobias_k

Comment: Do you understand now @tobias_k?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
def trigonometry(angle, side_length, side_respective_to_angle, unknown):
    sohcahtoa = [
        ['opposite', 'hypotenuse', 'adjacent'],
        [None, math.sin, math.tan],
        [math.sin, None, math.cos],
        [math.tan, math.cos, None]
    ]
    index1 = sohcahtoa[0].index(side_respective_to_angle)
    index2 = sohcahtoa[0].index(unknown)
    function = sohcahtoa[index1 + 1][index2]
    return (side_length / function(math.radians(angle))
        if side_respective_to_angle == 'opposite' or (side_respective_to_angle == 'adjacent' and unknown == 'hypotenuse')
        else function(math.radians(angle) * side_length))
```

Result for `trigonometry(30, 2, 'hypotenuse', 'opposite')` is `1` (more or less).

You have to get the `index` of the `[0]`th element for both `index1` and `index2`. Also, you have to convert the `angle` to `radians` first, as that's what the `math` function expect. Also, note that I only put the functions into the list, not the result of the function. No need to calculate them all beforehand.

But instead of that nested list, you could also use a nested dictionary, making the code a tiny bit easier to comprehend and not needing those index offsets. You can put the operator `*` or `/`) into the dictionary, too.

```
from operator import mul, truediv
import math
def trigonometry(angle, side_length, side_respective_to_angle, unknown):
    o, h, a = 'opposite', 'hypotenuse', 'adjacent'
    sohcahtoa = {o: {h: (math.sin, truediv), a: (math.tan, truediv)},
                 h: {o: (math.sin, mul),     a: (math.cos, mul)},
                 a: {o: (math.tan, mul),     h: (math.cos, truediv)}}
    function, op = sohcahtoa[side_respective_to_angle][unknown]
    return op(side_length, function(math.radians(angle)))
```

Comment: I like the dictionary. However, @tobias_k if I called `trigonometry(30, 1, 'opposite', 'hypotenuse')` then the function would return 0.5 (it should be 2). This is because you don't always multiply `function(math.randians(angle))` by `side_length`. For example in the case above, you must do `side_length / function(math.radians(angle)).

Comment: This could be fixed via `return side_length / function(math.radians(angle)) if side_respective_to_angle == 'opposite' or (side_respective_to_angle == a and unknown == h) else function(math.radians(angle) * side_length)` instead of `return function(math.radians(angle)) * side_length` but this is still a brute force style solution. Any way to improve this?

Comment: @MilanTom Right, forgot about that. You can also put that operator into the dict, too. See my edit.

Comment: Thank you @tobias_k, that is exactly what I want!

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't quite what you were going for, but I sort of brute forced every possibility for you.

```py
import math

# trig(angle=30, side=2, known='hyp', unknown='opp')
# This would want to find the length of a leg of a triangle
# that has a hypotenuse of 2, and an angle between the
# hypotenuse and another leg of 30 (degrees)

# sin(T) = opp / hyp
# cos(T) = adj / hyp
# tan(T) = opp / adj

def trig(angle, side, known, unknown):
    angle = math.radians(angle)
    # Unknown poss:
        # hyp
        # opp
        # adj
    if known == 'hyp':
        if unknown == 'opp':
            return known * math.sin(angle)
        elif unknown == 'adj':
            return known * math.cos(angle)

    elif known == 'opp':
        if unknown == 'hyp':
            return known / math.sin(angle)
        elif unknown == 'adj':
            return known / math.tan(angle)

    elif known == 'adj':
        if unknown == 'hyp':
            return known / math.cos(angle)
        elif unknown == 'opp':
            return known * math.tan(angle)
```

Comment: This does work but I want something were a dictionary or list is used and the code pulls the information from there. Thanks anyway though.